# Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a bunch of functions, which create portions of computation graph. In some of such functions I do

```
    with tf.name_scope("my_scope_name"):
        self._eye_n_components = tf.eye(se...
```

At the beginning of topmost function I call

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

and then call those partial functions and also they can call each other.

Unfortunately, I get an error

> Error: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. If
>   you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.

Several questions.

1) What is nesting and how to "exit nesting"?

2) How to create new graph?

3) How to catch, where I am entering the nesting?

4) How to clear entire graph so that tensorflow does not think I am trying to clear nested one?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error message is displayed when you call `tf.reset_default_graph()` in one of the following scenarios:

- Inside a `with graph.as_default():` block.
- Inside a `with tf.Session():` block.
- Between creating a `tf.InteractiveSession` and calling `sess.close()`.

Each of these scenarios involves registering a default (and potentially "nested") `tf.Graph` object, which will be unregistered when you exit the block (or close the `tf.InteractiveSession`). Resetting the default graph in those scenarios would leave the system in an inconsistent state, so you should ensure to exit the block (or close the `tf.InteractiveSession`) before calling `tf.reset_default_graph()`.

Comment: I just did `sess.close()`, and after that `tf.reset_default_graph()`, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by closing a session and loading the neural network model again.

My answers are: 
(1) Exit `with...` block or `sess.close()` 
(2) Load neural network model (and trained weight) like:

```
    gd = tf.GraphDef.FromString(open(checkpoint + '_frozen.pb', 'rb').read())
    inp, predictions = tf.import_graph_def(gd, return_elements=['input:0', 'MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1:0'])
```

(3) When you print out `model` you may see like Tensorflow object `<VSR.Backend.TF.Framework.Trainer.VSR object at 0x000001E5DA53C898>`
(4) I heard `tf.reset_default_graph()` and `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14356#issuecomment-343022733), but I never make the code work.