# How to clear GPU memory after using Tensorflow Graph/Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-lab

I am trying to clear GPU memory after using Tensorflow Graph/Session under Jupyter Lab. After finishing my training and inference steps I want to release all GPU memory used by my graph.

I used `tf.reset_default_graph()` after and before closing my session using `session.close()`, but without success. When I used `tf.reset_default_graph()` nested to a `with self.graph.as_default():` block, but the following exception was threw:

```py
~\git\myproject\model\mymodel.py in close(self)
    459             self.session.close()
    460 
--> 461             tf.reset_default_graph()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in reset_default_graph()
   5586   """
   5587   if not _default_graph_stack.is_cleared():
-> 5588     raise AssertionError("Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear "
   5589                          "nested graphs. If you need a cleared graph, "
   5590                          "exit the nesting and create a new graph.")

AssertionError: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. 
If you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.
```

My final version of the close method, but that is not working too, is described below:

```py
def close(self):
    """
    It closes the session and clears the graph
    :return: None
    """

    with self.graph.as_default():
        self.session.close()

    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

I am using `Tensorflow r1.14`. I can't update to `2.0` for now. I am not using `keras` once I am building my own graph using Tensorflow (python) primitives (e.g., `tf.add`, `tf.multiple`, `tf.random_normal`, `tf.placeholder`).

When my notebook is shutdown, my GPU memory is released as expected. But I have multiple models that are run sequentially.

How can I close my session and graph and clear my GPU memory under a Jupyter Lab environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not use tf.reset\_default\_graph() to clear nested graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893824/do-not-use-tf-reset-default-graph-to-clear-nested-graphs)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, gorjan. But that post did not work for me.